# angularjs override service setter and getter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angularjs-factory

I'm new to JS and angular,
I have a `currentUser` service in angular... It should set the current user retrieved to the `localStorage` to persist it between page refreshes

the service is defined as follows

```
var currentUserSrvc = function() {
  // some logic on how to save the user to localStorage
  return {
    user: {}
  };
};
angular.module('app').factory('currentUser', currentUserSrvc);
```

I want to override the setters and getters for this service to work with `localStorage`... but without adding setters and getters manually

don't mind how the localStorage internals will work

```
// I just want to use it like
currentUser.user = response.user
// instead of using it like (given that I'll provide a setter and a getter methods)
currentUser.setUser(response.user)
```

is that possible using angular js ?

Comment: so you want to add a $watcher to this service, to watch changes on user, right?

Comment: no I want to override the setters and getters in the service to allow extra logic injected in them.

Comment: unfortunately in javascript there's no internal setter/getter to properties (like some languages), you must add a $watcher to watch changes on properties (just like angularjs do)

Comment: the `service.__proto__` has the following methods `__defineGetter__` `__defineSetter__` `__lookupGetter__` `__lookupSetter__` ... Isn't angular using those as setters and getters in when `currentUser.user = ...` ?!

Comment: For reasons I don't know, this feature is being removed on latest versions of modern browsers, take a look at this page and se a deprecated note: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__ Unfortunately as far as I know, $watcher is the only option

Comment: @SergioFilhow lies, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: actually this work, please disconsider my comments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var currentUserSrvc = function() {
  // some logic on how to save the user to localStorage

  return {
     get user() {return localStorage.user;},
     set setUser(user) {localStorage.user = user}
  };
};
angular.module('app').factory('currentUser', currentUserSrvc);
```

This is how you use getters and setters in javascript:

So you would:

```
currentUser.user //retrieves localStorage.user
currentUser.setUser = "myUser" //sets localStorage.user to "myUser"
```

EDIT: Alternative you can do this.

```
var currentUserSrvc = function() {
  var currentUser = {}
  Object.defineProperty(currentUser, "user", {
    get: function() {return localStorage.user; },
    set: function(user) { localStorage.user = user; }
  })

  return currentUser;
};
angular.module('app').factory('currentUser', currentUserSrvc);
```

So you would:

```
currentUser.user //retrieves localStorage.user
currentUser.user = "myUser" //sets localStorage.user to "myUser"
```

EDIT2: Or you could even do this:

```
var currentUserSrvc = function() {
  // some logic on how to save the user to localStorage

  return {
     get user() {return localStorage.user;},
     set user(user) {localStorage.user = user}
  };
};
angular.module('app').factory('currentUser', currentUserSrvc);
```

Comment: I'm using coffeescript so both the first and last solution could not be applied... and the second solution works... but when I added a log to it I noticed that `currentUser.user = { someObject }` logged 1 setter call and 3 getter calls ?!

Comment: I've marked it as answer although that I didn't figure out why 1 setter and 3 getter calls when using it like `currentUser.user = { name: 'name', title: 'title', email: 'email' }` ?!

Comment: @artmees not sure, It only calls the setter once in mine and 0 times the getter when I run "currentUser.user = { name: 'name', title: 'title', email: 'email' }" in the console.